# Excel: Automatically update unshared PivotTables without ungrouping fields

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have some very simple code to automatically refresh my pivot tables when the data source is updated:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Sheet2.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotCache.Refresh
Sheet3.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotCache.Refresh
Sheet4.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotCache.Refresh

End Sub
```

Whenever it refreshes, my fields ungroup. For example one is in months the other is in weeks, etc. but when it refreshes they all ungroup and show each individual date. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is to record a macro that groups the data into the format that you want. Then copy the macro section that groups the selection after each pivot table refresh command. So essentially you refresh and regroup each time.

A link that shows how you can use VBA to group pivot table data is http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=55370

I hope this helps